# If protein poisoning is caused by a lack of dietary fats, why isn't it more prevalent?

Tags: nutrition, malnutrition

From what I've read about protein poisoning/rabbit starvation, the issue is a complete lack of fats in the diet. The malnutrition symptoms are pretty bad, and it's telling that cravings can only be satisfied by eating fats and oils.

What confuses me is the few times they attempt to quantify how much fat we need. Nothing precise, but I've read as much as 50/50 meat and fat from an animal. I don't eat nearly that much fat, I think, and yet I'm clearly not suffering from protein poisoning (to be more precise, a typical meal has a small handful of starchy carbs, a similar volume in meat or fish, and almost twice that volume in cooked greens).

Is there just a lot of invisible fat in our food, or does some other vital nutrient come into play?

Comment: Where did you read the 50/50 number? Please add a link.

Comment: I think I might have misremembered. A Google search including the terms "half" or "50%" doesn't turn up anything.

Comment: Not being a new user here you know we require prior research and being able to cite where you "heard something" is high on the list of what we require. So I'm going to close this but you can edit it with new information if you find it and it may be reopened.

Comment: My apologies, I'm too used to the more lax stackexchange sites

Comment: No apologies necessary, but I think you'll find that most of the scientific and academic sites have the same requirement.

Comment: @CareyGregory, my guess is Wikipedia's article on [protein poisoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_poisoning): the line on pemmican could easily be mis-remembered as indicating a need for 50% fat.